# How can I disable the node page for a specific content type? (But still use colorbox-node)

Tags: nodes, javascript

I use colorbox en colorbox-node to show the content of a node but I don't want people to access the node page for that content type.

How can I disable the node's detailpage and still access all the content in colorbox-node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In node.tpl.php you can test if node is accessed directly, and if so - redirect him to page with the same node inside colorbox. Or any other page, of course.

Comment: By checking the arg variables or is there a hook or something to check if node is accessed directly?

Comment: There is no hook for that, as the only mode node.module knows about is direct one. Modules that provide other ways of access are supposed to provide needed hooks or variables. If colorbox doesn't, you can set variable in template for colorbox and then test for it in node's one, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the "view mode" in your node template.

```
$view_mode: View mode; for example, "full", "teaser", "colorbox".
```